# Threaded State Machines in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, switch-statement, synchronized, state-machine

Is there a way of Holding a thread in a State waiting for changes?
I mean wait tll something happend (change var, call method, etc..)
perhaps it needs using Event Listeners, or synchronized objects/methods..

The usual aproach for statemachines like this

[statemachine example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255797/uses-for-state-machines/256011#256011)

That uses a do{..}while(true) loop that could work for singled threaded(and no GUI) application but it CANT'T be used with threads.. 
(at least you want to use a core for every threaded state machine)

So to avoid that processor consuming task a simple (and ugly) way 
is a "periodic checker", I mean adding a Sleep
other idea is defining a synchronized object and using wait instead of thread Sleep

example:

```
do{
    Switch(state)
    {         
        case STATE_A:
            //..A things                         
            break;

        case STATE_B:
            //..B things                         
            break;

        ...

        case STATE_Z:
            //..Z things                         
            break;
    }
    // Here!  =>   wait()?  Thread.sleep(TIME_CONST)? //Hold and yield
}while(powerOn);
```

The drawback is adding complexity using synchronized or that anything that happen within TIME_CONST would be invisible

I would like to know other ideas for doing this, 
thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you would be using `wait`/`notify`. That is what it is for.

Or maybe your state machine does not need to have its own thread. Other threads could call an `update` method on the state machine when something interesting happens.

Comment: I see it, that I thought was complex, is the simplest way!, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you specify a **queued** state machine in Umple then the code for this will be generated for you. Specifying an umple state machine as queued specifically creates a thread that waits for events (named method calls). Other code in the class can happen concurrently in the original thread(s). The keyword 'queued' should be placed just before the definition of the state machine.

See http://statemachines.umple.org for more information about creating state machines in Umple. You can consider Umple as just a preprocessor for Java (and for other languages) in this context.

Comment: Looks awesome! +1, I will give it a try. I think you could have answered this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946213/petri-net-drawing-and-code-generation

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Lock and [Condition](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) (Java 1.5+). It's like `wait/notify` and there is an example in the javadoc

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [Pipe](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Pipe.html) between the event source thread and the FSM embodiment thread.  This is sufficient for a 2 threaded implementation.